# Finding duplicates in SQL based on OR clause conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Take the imaginary schema representing products in a MySQL v5.6.41 db:

```sql
 ------------------------------------------------
| id | name | vendor_id | vendor_sku | upc | ean |
|----|------|-----------|------------|-----|-----|
| 1  | AAAA | 2         | 5678       | 456 | 111 | [1]
| 2  | aaaa | 2         | 7878       | 789 | 222 | [1]
| 3  | bbbb | 2         | 1234       | 111 | 333 | [2]
| 4  | cccc | 2         | 1234       | 222 | 444 | [2]
| 5  | dddd | 2         | 1111       | 123 | 555 | [3]
| 6  | eeee | 2         | 2222       | 123 | 666 | [3]
| 7  | ffff | 2         | 3333       | 333 | 777 | [4]
| 8  | gggg | 2         | 4444       | 444 | 777 | [4]
| 9  | hhhh | 2         | 5555       | 555 | 888 |
| 10 | iiii | 2         | 6666       | 666 | 999 |
| 11 | jjjj | 2         | 7777       | 777 | 000 |
| 12 | kkkk | 2         | 8888       | 888 | 001 |
| 13 | llll | 2         | 9999       | 999 | 002 |
| 14 | mmmm | 2         | 0000       | 000 | 003 | 
------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to find the count of duplicate rows that match one of the following criteria:

1. Same `vendor_id` and same `vendor_sku` **OR**
2. Same `vendor_id` and same `name` (case insensitive) **OR**
3. Same `vendor_id` and same `upc` **OR**
4. Same `vendor_id` and same `ean`

(The `[n]` notation next to each row would correspond to which condition these rows are duplicates on)

I've gathered this query so far, but this will only match condition #1:

```sql
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    vendor_id, vendor_sku
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

And my expected result would be 8 based on this example

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Shawn version 5.6.41

Answer (score 2):

I think `exists` might work:

```
select count(*)
from my_table t
where exists (select 1
              from my_table t2
              where t2.vendor_id = t.vendor_id and
                    t2.id <> t.id and
                    (t2.vendor_sku = t.vendor_sku or
                     t2.name = t.name or
                     t2.upc = t.upc or
                     t2.ean = t.ean
                    )
             );
```

Note that case sensitivity depends on your collation.  I haven't added in explicit handling for case (I would just use `lower()`) because it is not clear that such handling is necessary.

Comment: Hi Gordon, what you think about UNION ALL with all of the GROUP BY in a CTE and SUM all of the COUNT ?

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . Thank you!

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta MySQL 5x doesn't have CTE. MySQL8+ does. In general though, CTEs are good but can be expensive on large data sets. `GROUP BY` can be resource-intensive. I used to not like correlated subqueries because they didn't look as clean, but Gordon's solution should be very performant. Especially with how `EXISTS` can short-circuit value checking.

Answer (score 0):

I still think there are possible options to do this without using dependent sub-query.
When I was able to rid off dependent sub-query the execution plan usually became better.

So:

```
SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id)
FROM
    my_table AS t1
    INNER JOIN my_table AS t2 ON (
            t1.vendor_id = t2.vendor_id
        AND t1.id != t2.id
        AND (
               t1.vendor_sku = t2.vendor_sku
            OR t1.name = t2.name
            OR t1.upc = t2.upc
            OR t1.ean = t2.ean
        )
    )
```

OR:

```
SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id)
FROM
    my_table AS t1
    LEFT JOIN my_table AS t2 ON (
            t1.vendor_id = t2.vendor_id
        AND t1.id != t2.id
        AND (
               t1.vendor_sku = t2.vendor_sku
            OR t1.name = t2.name
            OR t1.upc = t2.upc
            OR t1.ean = t2.ean
        )
    )
WHERE
    t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

P.S. I did not have time to fix my previous answer when pointed on mistake so I used del tag instead of deleting the answer (sorry for that). Later I wanted to fix it, but answer was deleted by moderator.